# How to set the zoom level of the map view making exact three pins visible?

Tags: android, maps

My map view contains many pinpoints.When ever the user takes that activity the map should be zoomed in such a level the correct 3 pints are visible.The map should not be zoomed more or less it should be exactly three.I know zoom level of the map can be varied from 0 to 21 through code.But is there any way to set the zoom level in such a way that exact 3 pins are visible in both the cases if the pins are far or near correct 3 should be visible?Is there any functionality in the API to set like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With points being all the geopoints you want to be visible on your map.

```
private void Zoom() {
    int minLatitude = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maxLatitude = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int minLongitude = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maxLongitude = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (GeoPoint p : points) {
        int lati = p.getLatitudeE6();
        int lon = p.getLongitudeE6();

        maxLatitude = Math.max(lati, maxLatitude);
        minLatitude = Math.min(lati, minLatitude);
        maxLongitude = Math.max(lon, maxLongitude);
        minLongitude = Math.min(lon, minLongitude);
    }
    mapController.zoomToSpan(Math.abs(maxLatitude - minLatitude),
            Math.abs(maxLongitude - minLongitude));
    mapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint((maxLatitude + minLatitude) / 2,
            (maxLongitude + minLongitude) / 2));
}
```